# Find the missing number (HackerRank general cognitive test question)

Tags: pattern

HackerRank general cognitive test has the following question that I cannot solve:

**Please find the missing number:**

```
6 8 6 2 4
2 9 7 8 9
9 8 ? 1 3
```

Can you help me understand the logic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is

> 4

It's

> simply addition between two 5-digit numbers. The sum of those two numbers equal the last row.